# What is this plastic white thing that came with my motherboard?

Tags: motherboard

This came with my motherboard in a bag. Next to a tiny speaker I stick it in the motherbother next to the power switch & power/hdd LED. I would like to know What is it? Where do I put it? And what is it used for?

[image]

Comment: Was it only one? Is it hollow or solid?

Comment: @DanielAndersson: Yes there is only one. The face on the left side is solid. You can kind of see in the pic that the sphere isn't a full spear as there are 4 groves on it (you can see 2 kind of well in this pic).

Comment: It's a "standoff".

Comment: @DanH: Where do i put it and how do i use it? I have brass screws (2 of them) and i managed to put one in. There appears to be no other slots on the case to put the other in. Anyways, theres no way to screw the back of that (unlike the brass ones). How do i use this standoff?

Comment: Generally it goes into a hole on the solder side of the motherboard, in a place where there is no hole in the case, but where the motherboard might flex so much as to contact the case.  Like under the memory sockets.

Comment: @DanH: Hmm, ok, how do i apply it? Do i press the right side (in the pic above) face down? The only holes i see are places to put screws. So far i put regular screws there.

Comment: You press the pointy end into the hole in the motherboard.  There's very likely an extra hole in the motherboard you didn't see (though it may be that the part is supplied in case one of the screw holes in the motherboard doesn't correspond to a screw hole in the case -- not every part in such a kit must be used).

Answer (score 3):

This is either a device for connecting the CPU cooler with your motherboard or something you can put below your motherboard in order to prevent it from touching the chassis. I have seen this thing a lot of times when buying gaming PCs with heavy CPU coolers. Those coolers put a lot of pressure on the motherboard because of their weight. Those white things are there for "helping" the motherboard to relief some pressure.

Comment: hmmm. Ok so I tried sticking it in holes and the only place it seems to fit is where i put screws. Here is a pic http://i.imgur.com/dVhbi.jpg I put a brass screw in the blue circle there. Theres 4 other places. I put regular screws in the other holes (is this wrong?). This doesnt appear to fit anywhere except in the places i screw down. Theres nothing anywhere that appears to need it

Comment: Haha, this is really a though one! Well, your motherboard seems to have holes for the screws, so these white things are not needed for adjusting the motherboard.

Comment: So the only thing left would be that the white devices are there to hold the CPU cooler.

Comment: No, it's definitely a standoff, your motherboard doesn't know if your case will have a spot to put it or not. Your case has raised spots for the screws, which is nice, but not all do.

Answer (score 0):

It could be simply to protect the motherboard to mistakenly make contact with the walls of the desktop tower.

Comment: I dont understand how. The green circle had a brass standoff. I had two come in a bag so i put one in the blue circle. http://i.imgur.com/cTc97.jpg Theres no place i can put the other brass one and if this is a standoff i am cluesless how it works. There is no screw on the back and i dont see a place i can use this

Comment: Check the back side, upper center of the MB, in the area of the CPU, and see if there's a hole.  If not, then likely you don't need the part.

Comment: @DanH in the pic linked in the comment you can see a hole directly to the bottom left side of the CPU. But, it doesnt fit there. So... I have no idea